# Using Moq to setup generic methods where the type is not known until runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, moq

When using Moq in .NET, is there any way to setup a method that uses a generic type if I don't know what the type will be until runtime? Specifically, I'm looping over properties on a class using reflection, and I'd like to use the type of each property as a generic for a method on my mocked object. From what I've seen in Moq, setting up a generic method requires you to specify the types at compile time. The setup I want to do is a standard returns where I've already built the value I'd like the method to return when it's called with a specific type.

Comment: Add a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no from my understanding. The whole Moq library is designed with the purpose of knowing the mock type statically. This will allow you to know which properties can be configured.

Although,
A valid alternative is to create an expression using you runtime type and compile it to a function. This will allow you to use Moq library with dynamic types for sure, but I don't think worth the effort.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
Type ourRuntimeType; // get me from somewhere
Type mockType = typeof(Mock<>);
Type genericMockType = mockType.MakeGenericType(ourRuntimeType);
ConstructorInfo ctor = genericMockType.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>())!;
object ourNewInstance = ctor.Invoke(null);
```

Consider verifying that `ourRuntimeType` isn't a `ValueType` before doing this.